# How do programs estimate how long a process will take to complete?

Tags: time, loading, calculation

In some loading bars there will be something like "2 minutes remaining". Does the programmer time how long the process takes on their computer and use that value some how? Or does the program calculate it all itself? Or another method?

Answer (score 1):

This calculation is actually done internally because timing how long it would take to execute or download a certain program is based on internet speed, RAM, processor speed, etc. so it would be hard to have one universally predicted time based on the programmer's computer. Typically how this is calculated is based on how much of the program is already downloaded in comparison to the size of the file and takes into account how long it took to download that much data. From there the program extrapolates how much longer it will take to finish your download based on how fast it has operated until that point in time.

Answer (score 1):

Those 'x minutes remaining' interface elements, which (ideally) indicate how much time it will take to complete a certain task are simply forecasts based on how long that task has taken so far, and how much work on that task has been accomplished.

For example, suppose I have a app that will upload a batch of images to a server (all of which are the same size, for simplicity).  Here's a general idea of how the code that indicates time remaining will work:

Before we begin, we assign the current time to a variable. Also, at this point the time remaining indicator is not visible.  Then, in a for... loop:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < batchOfImages.length; i++)
{
```

1. We upload an image
2. After the image is uploaded, we get the difference between the current time and the start time.  This is the total time expended on this task so far.
3. We then divide the total time expended by the total number of images uploaded so far, `i + 1`, to get the amount of time it has taken on average to upload each image so far
4. We then multiply the average upload time per image by the number of images remaining to upload to get the likely amount of time it will take to upload the remaining images
5. We update the text on the indicator to show amount of time remaining, and we make sure that the indicator is visible

```js
}
```